# How to extract corporate bonds informations using machine learning

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, information-extraction

I am working on a project where I need to extract corporate bonds information from the unstructured emails. After doing a lot of research, I found that machine learning can be used for information extraction. I tried Opennlp NER (Named entity recognizer) but I am not sure whether I picked up the correct library for this problem or not because I am getting the results but not up to the mark.

Could someone please suggest me any library or algorithms means how can I parse and extract data from it. I am planning to explore Naïve Bayes or N-gram or Support vector machine but not sure, this will help me or not. Please suggest.

Examples are like:

`[/] Trading 10mm ABC 2.5 19   05/06 mkt  can use 50mm` ---> here I want to extract `"ABC 2.5 19"`

Example 2:

`XYZ 6.5   15 10-2B    106-107                B3   AAA- 1.646MM 2x2`   ---> here I want to extract `"XYZ 6.5   15"`

Comment: Have you tried pattern matching with regex? From what it looks like, you want to match 3 letters followed by a decimal followed by an integer/long (regardless of the number of spaces between them) which a well crafted regex should be able to handle pretty fast.

Comment: Initially, I suggested to use regex only but regex are tricky and not reliable for this type of cases as data is unstructured. Moreover I am looking for a technique where I can parse 05/06 or 106-107 or 2X2 values as well along with 3 letters, so I believe Machine learning would be better choice for this.

Comment: I've worked a little bit with FFNN and grammar parsing in the past and I don't think it would be the best solution for your case (although I would be very happy to be proven wrong). What about this instead? 1)Tokenize the entire email first. 2)browse through the tokens until you come across a 3 letter word 3)look at the next token to see if it's valid (you need to write feature classes to handle this for you 4)if valid, parse the next token and so on and so forth until you reach the end of the state machine and deem it a valid answer or if you reach an invalid state, go to next 3 letter char.

Comment: I would recommend a rule language like [JAPE](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html) or [UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html) before starting with machine learning. At least you get your labeled examples faster if not the task is already solved.

Comment: @PeterKluegl : I will look at them, looks interesting. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2) — a general BNF parser.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/rns/8241288fe9351f29a28a) extracts info from your examples.

Hope this helps.