# Parse values from a block of text based on specific keys

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm parsing some text from a source outside my control, that is not in a very convenient format.  I have lines like this:

> Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.

I want to split the line by keys like this:

```
Problem_Category = "Human Endeavors"
Problem_Subcategory = "Space Exploration"
Problem_Type = "Failure to Launch"
Software_Version = "9.8.77.omni.3"
Problem_Details = "Issue with signal barrier chamber."
```

The keys will always be in the same order, and are always followed by a semi-colon, but there is not necessarily space or newlines between a value and the next key.  I'm not sure what can be used as a delimiter to parse this, since colons and spaces can appear in the values as well. How can I parse this text?

Comment: The best solution, if possible, is "track down the developer whose code is creating that block of text, and ask them to output it as something more parseable, such as JSON". Then you don't need to do any regex/split trickery at all!

Comment: I am that developer! I am reading data from a massive Excel file. This Excel file is coming from a database, which in turn is coming from another database. Should I post the code I've written? I figured it would be a distraction from what I'm trying to accomplish, but maybe (apparently?) I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Also, I can't programmatically access this data directly from the database for this problem. Please let me know if there is further ambiguity I can resolve here.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid by not posting my code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

If your block of text is this string:

```
text = 'Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.'
```

Then

```
import re
names = ['Problem Category', 'Problem Subcategory', 'Problem Type', 'Software Version', 'Problem Details']

text = 'Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.'

pat = r'({}):'.format('|'.join(names))
data = dict(zip(*[iter(re.split(pat, text, re.MULTILINE)[1:])]*2))
print(data)
```

yields the dict

```
{'Problem Category': ' Human Endeavors ',
 'Problem Details': ' Issue with signal barrier chamber.',
 'Problem Subcategory': ' Space Exploration',
 'Problem Type': ' Failure to Launch',
 'Software Version': ' 9.8.77.omni.3'}
```

So you could assign

```
text = df_dict['NOTE_DETAILS'][0]
...
df_dict['NOTE_DETAILS'][0] = data
```

and then you could access the subcategories with dict indexing:

```
df_dict['NOTE_DETAILS'][0]['Problem_Category']
```

Caution, though. Deeply nested dicts/DataFrames of lists of dicts is usually a
bad design. As the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says, *Flat is better than nested.*

Comment: I see (and appreciate!) what you've suggested, but I can't use colons as delimiters. I need to use "Problem Category:" for example as the first delimiter. I will update my question to be more specific as well.

Comment: If the category names do not contain colons themselves, then you could split on the *first* colon using `line.split(':', 1)`. I've updated my answer with an example (note in particular the `ProductID` line).

Comment: The category names contain colons, and the colon is part of the category name. Your edit to my question was misleading because the block of text does not contain newlines (I rolled it back).

Comment: @JesseBikman: [the code works for the input in your question](http://ideone.com/pneRRk). `re.split()` is the elegant solution if the list of keywords is known. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you know the keywords ahead of time, partition the text into "current keyword", "remaining text", then continue to partition the remaining text with the next keyword.

```
# get input from somewhere
raw = 'Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.'

# these are the keys, in order, without the colon, that will be captured
keys = ['Problem Category', 'Problem Subcategory', 'Problem Type', 'Software Version', 'Problem Details']
prev_key = None
remaining = raw
out = {}

for key in keys:
    # get the value from before the key and after the key
    prev_value, _, remaining = remaining.partition(key + ':')

    # start storing values after the first iteration, since we need to partition the second key to get the first value
    if prev_key is not None:
        out[prev_key] = prev_value.strip()

    # what key to store next iteration
    prev_key = key

# capture the final value (since it lags behind the parse loop)
out[prev_key] = remaining.strip()

# out now contains the parsed values, print it out nicely
for key in keys:
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, out[key]))
```

This prints:

```
Problem Category: Human Endeavors
Problem Subcategory: Space Exploration
Problem Type: Failure to Launch
Software Version: 9.8.77.omni.3
Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate and fear regex, so here's a solution using only built-in methods.

```
#splits a string using multiple delimiters.
def multi_split(s, delims):
    strings = [s]
    for delim in delims:
        strings = [x for s in strings for x in s.split(delim) if x]
    return strings

s = "Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber."
categories = ["Problem Category", "Problem Subcategory", "Problem Type", "Software Version", "Problem Details"]
headers = [category + ": " for category in categories]

details = multi_split(s, headers)
print details

details_dict = dict(zip(categories, details))
print details_dict
```

Result (newlines added by me for readability):

```
[
    'Human Endeavors ', 
    'Space Exploration', 
    'Failure to Launch', 
    '9.8.77.omni.3', 
    'Issue with signal barrier chamber.'
]

{
    'Problem Subcategory': 'Space Exploration', 
    'Problem Details': 'Issue with signal barrier chamber.', 
    'Problem Category': 'Human Endeavors ', 
    'Software Version': '9.8.77.omni.3', 
    'Problem Type': 'Failure to Launch'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just the job for general BNF parsing which handles ambiguity nicely. I used perl and [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a general BNF parser. Hope this helps.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Marpa::R2;

my $g = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),

    :default ::= action => [ name, values ]

    pairs ::= pair+

    pair ::= name (' ') value

    name ::= 'Problem Category:'
    name ::= 'Problem Subcategory:'
    name ::= 'Problem Type:'
    name ::= 'Software Version:'
    name ::= 'Problem Details:'

    value ::= [\s\S]+

    :discard ~ whitespace
    whitespace ~ [\s]+

END_OF_SOURCE
} );

my $input = <<EOI;
Problem Category: Human Endeavors Problem Subcategory: Space ExplorationProblem Type: Failure to LaunchSoftware Version: 9.8.77.omni.3Problem Details: Issue with signal barrier chamber.
EOI

my $ast = ${ $g->parse( \$input ) };

my @pairs;

ast_traverse($ast);

for my $pair (@pairs){
    my ($name, $value) = @$pair;
    say "$name = $value";
}

sub ast_traverse{
    my $ast = shift;
    if (ref $ast){
        my ($id, @children) = @$ast;
        if ($id eq 'pair'){

            my ($name, $value) = @children;

            chop $name->[1];

            shift @$value;
            $value = join('', @$value);
            chomp $value;

            push @pairs, [ $name->[1], '"' . $value . '"' ];
        }
        else {
            ast_traverse($_) for @children;
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Problem Category = "Human Endeavors "
Problem Subcategory = "Space Exploration"
Problem Type = "Failure to Launch"
Software Version = "9.8.77.omni.3"
Problem Details = "Issue with signal barrier chamber."
```